# Why didn't Syaoran lose his memory?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

At the end of Cardcaptor Sakura Movie 2: The Sealed Card..

> As the sealed card appears to go to Sakura, it chooses Syaoran as the one who will lose their most important feelings because Sakura used too many cards at one time.

However..

> Crying and believing it's too late, but encouraged by the Hope Card, Sakura still confesses to Syaoran that she loves him and that he is her most important person. To her surprise, he gently replies that he loves her too, and Sakura realizes he didn't lose his feelings for her after all.

How was this possible? Was it because of the Hope Card?  I just need some explanation for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the Sealed Card was able to attack and gather Syaoran's most important feeling, the Hope Card negated it.

To explain it more clearly, it was because the nameless card nullified the power of the sealed card to obtain Syaoran's feelings. With regard to this, Sakura's powerful emotions towards Li made that happen. The Sealed card and the nameless card merged in the process, creating the Hope Card. That is why the Hope Card or the Love Card (which was called in the english dub) was the card who doesn't have a clow card counterpart, meaning it only exist as a Sakura Card because it was created by Sakura's feelings towards Li Syaoran.

Comment: What do you mean by negated? Is it a process?

Comment: As I understood back then (correct me if I'm wrong), the Hope Card was created because of Sakura's emotions plus the Sealed Card and the blank card. Am I incorrect?

Comment: To explain it more clearly, it was because the nameless card nullified the power of the sealed card to obtain Syaoran's feelings. With regard to this, sakura's powerful emotions towards Li had made that happen. Sealed card and the nameless merged in the process, creating the hope card. That is why the Hope Card or the Love Card (Which was called in the english dubbed) was the card who doesn't have a clow card counterpart, meaning it only exist as a Sakura Card because it was created by Sakura's feelings towards Li Syaoran...

Comment: I'm going to edit your answer because that explained better. :)

Comment: By the way, where did the nameless card came from anyway? -_-

Comment: the nameless card was then again, created because of the yearning feeling Sakura has for Syaoran when Syaoran returned back to Hong Kong. This answer will support the last statement I had stated above^^